# Backup Files in Google Drive with Google Apps Script

Tags: backup

I'm new in Google Apps Script, and I have been searching and trying to do a script that deletes the content of a folder (***folder a***) without going to trash, then copy another folder with content (***folder b***), and move the content of the copied folder (***copy of folder b***) to the first folder (***folder a***).

I know that this can be confusing but I can´t explain another way :(

Thanks :D

Comment: what platform ? windows ? or unix like ?

Comment: Give your question a more descriptive title to attract the right people, and elaborate more on your question as it is a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm using windows, and scripting in Google Apps Script :/

Answer (score 0):

For unix-like OSes:

```
rm -rf folderA
cp -pR folderB folderA
```